# passing data to already implemented delegate methods inside extensions inside swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift-extensions

I am trying to pass data to a delegate method implemented inside an extension but i am unable to do it since extensions cannot have stored properties. How to get it done?

Comment: Please post some code samples of your work and some examples of what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the stored property a requirement of the delegate protocol.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var aProperty: String { get set }
    func aProtocolMethod()
}
```

For the corresponding extension of MyProtocol, the property can be accessed directly.

```
extension MyProtocol {
    func aProtocolMethod() {
        print("property:" + aProperty)
    }
}
```

In the class which conforms to MyProtocol, it should implement the variable to store data.

```
 class MyClass: MyProtocol {
    var aProperty: String

    init() {
        self.aProperty = "some value"
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.aProtocolMethod()
```